# jQuery count down to 250 characters

Tags: jquery

Currently, on my website I have a character count of one of my text areas. So that they know how many characters they have typed so they know how many they have left.

What I am now realizing now though is it should really be a count down to the minimum number of characters and when they reach the maximum it should output the amount that is too much.

I'm not really sure how to go about this though. This is what I have right now, where I am just counting the length.

```
$('textarea[name="book_summary"]').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val().length < 250){
    $('.bookChar').html('<span style="color:green;">You have ' + $(this).val().length +' characters to go!</span>');
  }else if($(this).val().length >= 250){
    $('.bookChar').html('');
  }else if($(this).val().length >= 800){
    $('.bookChar').html('<span style="color:red;">You have ' + $(this).val().length +' too much!</span>');
  }
 });
```

Is it possible to count down to the 250 and then past 800? A jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JWWfY/7/

And I know it's not recommended to have a span within a span, but I'm just trying to get this working and then I'll go back and clean it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there's no need to re-obtain the length 3 times. That's wasted overhead.

Secondly, your character counts are showing the actual length of the text, and not what's left to go (or how far beyond the limit they are).

To address your actual issue, you need to wrap the `>=800` inside the `>=250` comparison, because otherwise one or the other will never execute.

```
$('textarea[name="book_summary"]').keyup(function(){
  var len = $(this).val().length;
  if ( len < 250 ){
    $('.bookChar').html('<span style="color:green;">You have ' + (250-len) +' characters to go!</span>');
  } else if( len >= 250 ){
      if ( len >= 800 ){
          $('.bookChar').html('<span style="color:red;">You have ' + (len-800) + ' too much!</span>');
      } else {
          $('.bookChar').html('');
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't need the nested `if`.  `if < 250  else if > 800 else ...`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but like I said in my post. I know that I had excess code, I was just trying to make it work before I went back and cleaned it up.

Comment: No worries, no judgment, just making sure you understood why I changed what I did.

Comment: dang you were too fast heh

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot clearer if you separate things out a bit, and you don't need all the if statements that make it more difficult to both read and understand.  This will do what you describe...

```
$('textarea[name="book_summary"]').keyup(function() {
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    var html = "";

    if (len < 250) {
        html = '<span style="color:green;">You have ' + (250 - len) +' characters to go!</span>';
    } else if (len > 800) {
        html = '<span style="color:red;">You have ' + (len - 800) +' too much!</span>';
    }

    $(".bookChar").html(html);
});
```

Comment: You missing a closing ( :) And I know it was a bit messy, like I said I just wanted to make it work before I cleaned it up.

Comment: @zazvorniki oops!  Thanks for spotting my mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check against the lower and upper thresholds and you can re-use the length from one variable.

I also fixed the submit check to make sure to check for 800 or fewer characters.

I like things simple so just if, else if, else will suffice in this case.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWWfY/11/)

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  var len = $('textarea[name="book_summary"]').val().length    
  if (len < 250){
    $('.bookError').html('This field must have at least 250 characters.');
  }else if(len > 800){
      $('.bookError').html('This field cannot have more than 800 characters.');
  } else {
      $('.bookError').html('');
  }
});

    $('textarea[name="book_summary"]').keyup(function(){ 
        var len = $(this).val().length;
        if(len < 250){
            $('.bookChar').html('<span style="color:green;">You have ' + (250 - len) +' characters to go!</span>');
        }else if(len > 800){
            $('.bookChar').html('<span style="color:red;">You have ' + (len - 800) +' too much!</span>');
        } else{
            $('.bookChar').html('');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To stick with your same format.  In your example if the length of the text is over 250 characters then the following is always true `else if($(this).val().length >= 250)` so it never gets to your last if statement.

I modified all three of your if statements to match what you are looking for in your question.

```
$('textarea[name="book_summary"]').keyup(function(){
            if($(this).val().length < 250){
                $('.bookChar').html('<span style="color:green;">You have ' + (250-$(this).val().length) +' characters to go!</span>');
            }else if($(this).val().length >= 250 && $(this).val().length <= 800){
                $('.bookChar').html('');
            }else if($(this).val().length > 800){
                $('.bookChar').html('<span style="color:red;">You have ' + ($(this).val().length-800) +' too much!</span>');
            }
        });
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/JWWfY/9/

Update (A little cleaner/more efficient):

```
$('textarea[name="book_summary"]').keyup(function(){
        var len = $(this).val().length;
        if(len < 250)
            $('.bookChar').html('<span style="color:green;">You have ' + (250-len) +' characters to go!</span>');
        else if(len > 800)
            $('.bookChar').html('<span style="color:red;">You have ' + (len-800) +' too much!</span>');
        else
            $('.bookChar').html('');
    });
```